# Why am I getting repeated Careers update emails?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email

In the last four hours, I've gotten three instances of this email:

> **Subject:** Done any cool projects lately? Add it to your Careers profile!
>
> Thanks for being a member of Stack Overflow Careers!
>
> We noticed that you haven’t edited your profile in a while. Have you changed jobs, written any blog posts, contributed to any open source projects lately? Update your profile to ensure employers can easily find you.
>
> Best,
>
> The Stack Overflow Careers Team

I could swear I've gotten even more than that, but I'm not seeing them now.

What gives?

Comment: Weird, I get those once every 3 months, unless editing the profile, which "reset" the timer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm really, really sorry about this. I made some changes in our email code yesterday that affected one of the queries used by a scheduled job to determine who to send emails to.

Unfortunately it sends emails one by one, but commits a batch to the DB at the end. In this case it had an error committing the batch so everytime it re-ran it resent an email to you. I'm checking to see how many people this affected, but I suspect you were at the start of the batch.

Again, really sorry about that :/

Needless to say the bug is now fixed and we're checking how to prevent the scenario from occurring again.

Comment: Fire! Fire! Oh wait, your hair is already on fire... :D